# Visual Studio allows binding temporary to class member, is this intended and ok to use?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

My code very closely resembles this:

```
Class A{
public:
    // B& b_instance;
    // A(B& b) : b_instance(b) {}
    // Code above works well in VC,
    // G++ gives an error when the class is initiated with a temporary object
    // I know this is illegal, but it's irrelevant for our matter
    // I ran following code :
    const B& b_instance;
    A(const B& b) : b_instance(b) {}
}

Class B{
public:
    int number;
    B(int i) : number(i) {}
}

int main(){
    B b0 = B(5);
    A a0 = A(b0);
    // This should print 5, and indeed it does
    std::cout << a0.b_instance.number<< '\n';

    // This should not work and g++ doesn't print anything at all 
    // unless the stream is flushed. MVSC works fine on the other hand
    A a1 = A(B(4));
    std::cout << a1.b_instance.number<< std::endl;

}
```

I have thousands of instances of both classes and I'm dynamically allocating memory in some places, so I think some new objects would be created at the address of extinct temporary objects. But after all, Visual studio compiles and runs fine. So is this a language extension? Should I continue working like this or change my class member so that it stores data by value:

```
Class A{
public:
    B b_instance;
    A(const B& b) : b_instance(b) {}
}
```

Edit: I want to add that, if the stream is flushed g++ prints "4" too. But according to C++ standards, this should be illegal. (a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696), http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)

Comment: The last line exhibits undefined behavior. `a1.b_instance` is a dangling reference. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I looked at [DR 1696](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1696) - I don't believe its resolution makes your example ill-formed. It's well-formed but exhibiting undefined behavior, before and after DR 1696.

Comment: Thanks, so this works but it can break at any moment? What could possibly make this statement throw an error or crash the program?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior , http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html